# Number of left cosets of the special linear group in the general linear group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $F$ be a field of cardinality $q$. I need to prove that $\frac{\left |{GL_n(F)}\right |}{\left |{SL_n(F)}\right |}=q-1$.

I try to find a bijection between the left cosets of ${\left |{SL_n(F)}\right|}$ in ${\left |{GL_n(F)}\right|}$ and the invertible elements of $F$, but I could not find this bijection.

Comment: There are $q-1$ possible determinants in $GL_n(F)$, so...

Comment: Yes, you can use determinants to show that $aI$ and $bI$ lie in different cosets of $SL_n(F)$ for $a\neq b \in F^*$.

Comment: Try the First Isomorphism theorem using the determinant homomorphism.

Answer (score 3):

The homomorphism $\operatorname{det}\colon GL_n(F)\to F^\times$ is a surjection, since for $q\in F^\times$, the block matrix 
$$
\begin{pmatrix} q & 0 \\ 0 & I_{n-1}\end{pmatrix}
$$
maps to $q$, for example. The kernel is $SL_n(F)$ by definition more or less.

So $GL_n(F)/SL_n(F)\simeq F^\times$, and you get the result.